# How to add second gradient wave?

Tags: android

I added such gradient as a background for my screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#0019A8"
        android:centerColor="#4C5CB1"
        android:endColor="#0019A8"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

there is a result that I got

[image]

So, at the middle I have one gradient stripe, **what I actually need is - two stripes**, first one closer to right left edge and second one to left bottom edge.

But, gradient give just 3 options for set color `start, center, end`.

So, question is - how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Use layer list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
<shape
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#0019A8"
        android:centerColor="#4C5CB1"
        android:endColor="#0019A8"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
</item>
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:gradientRadius="100"
        android:startColor="#14B2FF"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerX="0.5"
        android:centerY="0.75"/>
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Really? Do you see on your screenshot two stripes? first one closer to right left edge and second one to left bottom edge?

Comment: Mine was a suggestion on how achieve what do you want. You can adjust android:angle and other attributes to achieve yours.